# new to python web scraping

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://econpy.pythonanywhere.com/ex/001.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
#This will create a list of buyers:
buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
#This will create a list of prices
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]/text()')
print 'Buyers: ', buyers
print 'Prices: ', prices
```

I got this example

But I want to navigate to page to grab content

**Example:**

```
www.example.com/category/report
```

navigate to

```
www.example.com/category/report/annual
```

I have to grap pdf or xls or csv and save it in my system.
Suggest me the current trending python scraping tech  using xpath and Regular expression

i am waiting for the answer

Comment: Try looking into scrapy. I use it and it eases a lot of the pain of scraping.

Comment: thks ,may i know exact example code ?

may i know current trending web scarper in python which uses both xpath and regular expression ?

my frnds asking about scarping data stored in mangoDB ?

is it possible ?

can someone answer with example ..pls we are new to python scarping ?

request to give some step by step procedure to scarpe a site .
u can guide with website links,pdf,doc etc about scarping using python

Comment: This is not the kind of question for SO. It is much too broad. The framework that I suggested has tutorials and great documentation. I suggest you try it for yourself and when you run into stuff you don't understand ask a more specific question.  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/